# Should I port my Ubuntu VM to Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I've been spending a fair bit of time in a Linux VM, today I decided to try and get Docky to work, but it needs desktop effects.

To cut a long story short, the only VM solution that offers desktop effects seems to be VirtuaBox.

If I want to get better graphics support, is it a good idea to migrate over to Virtual Box?

Is the migration path simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I migrated yesterday and have been using it all day.

Performance wise I find it is slightly faster than VMWare 6.5, graphic rendering is smoother, also driver installation procedure seem much less intrusive.

The upgrade is a smooth as silk, the VMDK works just fine in Virtual Box.

I tried out the 3D features, but I must say that running compiz on the VM is not smooth enough, I seem to be getting artifacts and general tearing.

Comment: 3D support in guests is marginal at best, so this is no surprise.  If you need native 3D support, your only viable option is to run on physical hardware.

Comment: Or use a type-1 hypervisor with a dedicated graphics card for the VM (downside: out put will be always be full screen on a different monitor).

Answer (score 3):

I went from VMware to Virtualbox, and love the speed difference. I am not sure about the migration path though, because I just reinstalled from scratch.

Another thing great about VB is that the Free VMware player does not support shared folders, but VirtualBox does.

Comment: VMware Player supports shared folders.

Comment: @KovBal - Not with the free version.